# Flow-typed definitions being ignored in favor of npm module?

Tags: flowtype, flow-typed

Consider the following Javascript and Flow code:

```
import type { $Request, $Response } from 'express';

function middleware(req: $Request, res: $Response) {}

middleware({}, {});
```

(full code at https://github.com/bradvogel/flow-playground)

When `express` *isn't* installed as an npm module, Flow correctly flags the code error:

[image]

However, when I `npm install express`, Flow can no longer resolve the types (from flow-typed):

[image]

Can someone explain who Flow is trying to import the types from the Express module, versus from flow-typed? How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flow doesn't really know about Node packages as a unit, so if you don't want Flow to try to parse things in `node_modules`, you'll want

```
[ignore]
<PROJECT_ROOT>/node_modules/.*
```

in your `.flowconfig`. If you did want to allow a subset of node_modules, the [`[ignore]`](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/ignore/) explain how to do that.

I'm not aware of how Flow prioritizes explicitly-declared type definitions from `flow-typed` vs real files, but presumably given what we're seeing here, Flow must try to load type definitions from the actual imported file unless the file is ignored.